# Populate treeview tree from simple sql table c # code visual studio 2021

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a SQL table with four fields ID, Makro, Syper, Object. I want to fill the treeview tree in this order: Makro - level 1, Syper - level 2, Object - level 3. Each next level is a child of the previous one, how can I do it?

Comment: need C # code to insert into the project

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research."

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, I'm already confused ...